# query execution taking too long for altering table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql

I have a table called address and the table has a column called zip5 which is of type varchar(6) .

I am using query

```
alter table address change zip5 zip5 varchar(14);
```

but the query execution is taking too long I am waiting from almost 15 minutes and waiting for query to execute, the address table has 9.7 million records. Does it take this long for this amount of data or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `CHANGE` is intended for renaming columns, and I don't know what it will do if you try to rename to the same name (as you're doing). To change the data type, `MODIFY` is more appropriate:  `ALTER TABLE address MODIFY zip5 VARCHAR(14);`

Comment: Looks like this is normal check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774709/mysql-very-slow-for-alter-table-query

Comment: But 9.7M is a large table, and if an index has to be rebuilt it may take a long time.  To see its progress, do `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`

Comment: even i think so that index are causing a problem, there is index on address_id, state_id, and city_id columns in the table. but does modifying the column data-type really affect the performance of mysql

Comment: If there's no index on zip5 then I doubt that indexes are a factor - but I may be mistaken.

Comment: there is no index on zip5...deleted all the indexes on the table and tried to modify the column ,,,but still no change..

Comment: Why aren't you making it a char (14)?

Comment: i dont think so it will make any difference..but not sure

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I dont know why but

```
ALTER TABLE address MODIFY zip5 varchar(14)
```

seems to be a bit faster. At least on my system with a comparable table-structure.

`ALTER TABLE` makes a copy of you table. Perhaps the bottle-neck is your HD? Do you use SSDs? or is your temporary table storage not set on a fast disk? Is the disk full?

Comment: database is not in ssd, it is in normal hard-drive. disk is not full. I still have 480 GB of free space..