# How to convert an unsigned integer to big integer in big mySQL table

Tags: mysql, typeconverter

I have a mySQL table with 3 billions records. I had set Auto Increment `id` as `unSigned integer`. `id` is primary key. But now, it is reaching the upper limit. I want to convert my id field to `bigInteger`, but mySQL stops and waits for a long time.

How can I convert the id field to `bigInteger` without letting the project down?

I wanted to add column to this table before and waited 2 days. I had to cancel.

mySQL version: `5.7.14 (Google Cloud Sql)`

Table Engine: `InnoDB`

Comment: id is a primary key ?, do you have indexes based on id or others indexes ?, if yes, drop indexes , change type of field, then recreate indexes.

Comment: you can see also here : see answer : create a new table with same structure but with id as bigint, and use dump do export old and reimport to the new table.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774709/mysql-very-slow-for-alter-table-query