# Alter 100M rows Amazon RDS table to add a new column

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to add a new column to a very very large table, but my alter command fails miserably

```
mySQL [sc_production]> ALTER TABLE job_assets ADD COLUMN browser varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interruptedy
```

I've tried without the LOCK as well, but it also failed:

```
mySQL [sc_production]> ALTER TABLE job_assets ADD COLUMN browser varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,  ALGORITHM=INPLACE;
ERROR 1034 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table 'job_assets'; try to repair it
```

Is there any other way that I could do it ?
Creating a new table with this column and migrating all the data would be a huge huge pain

Edit:
I already have the max execution time set to 0

```
mySQL [sc_production]> show variables like '%max_execution_time%';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| max_execution_time | 0 |
```

Thanks

Comment: Related threads:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359097/mysql-alter-table-on-very-large-table-is-it-safe-to-run-it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774709/mysql-very-slow-for-alter-table-query

but no immediate answers. MySQL and table changes seem to be really slow and memory hungry for big tables. Might want to increase the available memory if possible.

Comment: I'll create a bigger RDS instance, with a lot more space and resources and see how it goes, maybe it's because of resources. I'll keep the topic updated once I finish testing